# How to redirect from backend (nodejs) to frontend (react)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redirect, post, callback

I want to add a submit form on a site with domain name `source.com` and when the user submits the button I want to redirect him to a site with domain name `target.com`. The app hosted at `target.com` has a backend at `backend.target.com` and a frontend at `frontend.target.com`.

On the `source.com` I have :

```
<form action="https://backend.target.com" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="textId" name="textName">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My problem is, that I want somehow to redirect the user on frontend after receiving the post request at backend. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Any alternative method would be helpful in case I am approaching this in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to have a service that does that. Submit the form though a REST service ([Look here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)), wait for the response, and based on that response decide where to navigate the client.

Your client can be something like

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React POST Request Example' })
};
fetch('http://someapi', requestOptions)
.then(response => //redirect to whereever)
```

Comment: When I try this, I get slammed by `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [...]. Status code: 403.
` errors. Do you know why or what the fix is?